# The natural map $V^*\otimes W\rightarrow \mathrm{Hom}(V, W)$ in infinite-dimensional case.

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, axiom-of-choice

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces over a field $K$. Define a function $\varphi:V^*\times W\to V^*\otimes W$ as $\varphi(f, w)= f\otimes w$.

Define a function $h:V^*\times W\to \mathrm{Hom}(V, W)$ as $h(f, w)(x)=f(x)w$. By the universal property of $\varphi$, there is a natural map $\tilde{h}:V^*\otimes W\to \mathrm{Hom}(V, W)$ such that $h=\tilde{h}\circ \varphi$.

I know that if $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional, $\tilde{h}$ is isomorphism.

Is $\tilde{h}$ generally injective or surjective?

If so, is it can be proved without using the assumption that every vector space has a basis (axiom of choice) ?

Comment: $\tilde{h}$ is injective, but not surjective because its range are all linear maps that have finite dimensional range. As far as i remember existence of a basis of an infinite dimensional space is not needed in the proof.

Comment: This has been asked before on MSE. Please try the search function. And yes the map is injective, but not surjective when both of the spaces are infinite-dimensional.